# Can I dynamically modify layout of a Dialog?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, dialog

I'm trying to get rid of NPE in this code:

```
Dialog  mutuallyDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
mutuallyDialog.requestWindowFeature(android.view.Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.layout.new_couple);
container.findViewById(R.id.popup_av2).setBackground(someDrawable); // NPE, drawable returned form elsewhere

mutuallyDialog.setContentView(container);
mutuallyDialog.show();
```

R.layout.new_couple is just a simple layout xml with some text and ImageViews popup_av1 and popup_av2.

What I want to achive is to be able to change these two ImageViews src before showing the dialog but for some reason above code is not working. Is this approach correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not call find view by Id for layouts like:

```
RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.layout.new_couple);
```

Instead you can set it as content view like:

```
mutuallyDialog.setContentView(R.layout.new_couple);
```

Now you can call find view by ID on mutuallyDialog to find views in your layout and change them:

```
mutuallyDialog.findViewById(R.id.popup_av2).setBackground(someDrawable);
```

Change your code to following:

```
Dialog  mutuallyDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
mutuallyDialog.requestWindowFeature(android.view.Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
mutuallyDialog.setContentView(R.layout.new_couple);
mutuallyDialog.findViewById(R.id.popup_av2).setBackground(someDrawable); 


mutuallyDialog.show();
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: This is correct, I've also combined it with Universal Image Loader and it works like a charm. Thanks!